# Best way to recover from a thread that fails to complete and handeling

Tags: c#, multithreading, dotnet-httpclient

I have an application that creates multiple threads to make HTTP requests. The issue I am facing is that if a request fails, the thread is aborted. I need some ideas on how to reissue the same request either in a new or existing thread. I am using a BlockingCollection to add and dequeu items that are pulled from the HTTP Request. This is not important, but it will help to understand what I am doing. Keep in mind, there are many reasons that an HTTP Request might fail, so I am not going to post the actual code for the request. I am using the HTTPClient class to make the requests.

Example code:

```
private void StartIntegration()
        {
            var queuCount = 0;

            var totalToSend = GetTotalToSendFromDb();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    while (queuCount != totalToSend)
                    {
                        //Get 500 items form the database to pass into the request                            
                        var items = GetRequestsFromDB(500);
                        if (items != null && items.Count > 0)
                        {
                            queuCount += items.Count;
                            SendRequest(mailing);
                        }


                    }
                });
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ConsumeResults());
            }

            while (_someGlobalVariable)
            {
                //Loop until the variable is false.

            }


        }
```

Comment: Instead of having the main thread spawn a new thread upon failure, you could have the spawned thread handle the exception and re-try the HTTP request.

Comment: That's just it, I am getting an AggregateException and the thread is aborted I tried then having the catch block reissue the request, but it never reissues it. Perhaps I am not handling the exception properly

Comment: Yes, please show the code for the http request threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging there were a few issues with the request and what was actually coming back. Originally, I was catching just a generic exception. After changing it to catch an AggregateException I was able to figure out the cause of the request error and in turn, I was able to call the method again. I added a variable to the method so it would only retry X amount of times before giving up.

Another Issue was how I was getting the data back from the database. The stored procedure looks like this:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetTopListEmailItems](

@topCount   INT) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      BEGIN 
          -- Identify the next N emails to be batched. UPDLOCK is to prevent another thread batching same emails
          SELECT TOP (@topCount) id 
          INTO   #tmpbatch 
          FROM  (SELECT  
                        Id, 
                        Md5Hash,
                                                EmailAddress,
                                                IsProcessed
                 FROM   ListEmailItems WITH (updlock,HOLDLOCK)) tmp 
          WHERE IsProcessed  = 0

          -- Stamp emails as sent. Assumed that PROC is called under a UOW. The batch IS the UOW 
          UPDATE e 
          SET    e.IsProcessed = 1 
          FROM   dbo.ListEmailItems e 
                 INNER JOIN #tmpbatch t 
                         ON e.id = t.id 

          -- Return the batch of emails to caller 
          SELECT e.* 
          FROM   dbo.ListEmailItems e 
                 INNER JOIN #tmpbatch t 
                         ON e.id = t.id 
      END 
  END
```

This procedure is supposed to only get the Top `X` records and block the threads so the same records are not pulled multiple times. The issue was with the C# code. After wrapping the DB call in a transaction, it was no longer pulling the same records multiple times.

```
private List<ListEmailItem> GetRequests(int topCount,bool reset = false)
        {
            List<ListEmailItem> items;
            using (var tran = new TransactionScope(
                // a new transaction will always be created
                TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew,
                // we will allow volatile data to be read during transaction
                new TransactionOptions()
                {
                    IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted
                }
                ))
            {
                using (var context = new IntegrationContext())
                {
                    items = context.Database.SqlQuery<ListEmailItem>("Exec GetTopListEmailItems @topCount",
                        new SqlParameter("topCount", topCount)).Select(s => new ListEmailItem()
                        {
                            Id = s.Id,
                            Md5Hash = s.Md5Hash,
                            EmailAddress = s.EmailAddress,

                        }).ToList();


                }

                tran.Complete();
            }

            return items;
        }
```